# How to convert real number between 0 to 1 into binary in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, real-number

I am trying to convert a real number (`a`) which is between zero and one to an array of bits.

I have tried this:

```js
let a = 0.625
let b = []
while (a != 0) {
    if ((a * 2) >= 1) {
        b.push(1)
        a = a - 1          
    }    
    else {
        b.push(0)  
    }
}
console.log(b)
```

But I get an error that says "something went wrong while displaying this webpage".

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Don't spam tags. Removing the `c` tag as there is _no_ C code here.

Comment: @CraigEstey nor is there Java code. And Xcode is straight wrong, it's an editor typically for Apple tech, like Swift. While web-development server has absolutely nothing to do with anyting. It's not even an application where you *might* write code.

Comment: By `a = 0.625` initial value, it is an **endless loop**. `while` condition never become **zero** to break the loop. You should use a condition like `a > 0` for `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because you just test if a * 2 is larger 1, but never actually multiply it by two you enter a infinite loop. You could do:

```
let a = 0.625
let b = []
while (a != 0) {
    a *= 2

    if (a >= 1) {
        b.push(1)
        a = a - 1
        
    }
    
    else {
        b.push(0)

    }
}
console.log(b)
```

Comment: thank you so much dude I forgot about that 